# Accessing data from Couchbase using java

Tags: java, couchbase

I want to access data from couchbase using java ViewQuery but unable to do that due to the following exception.

> net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder: Failed to
>   decompress data java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format

**Note:**- If That's important :-
I am storing the data in couchbase using PHP and trying to fetch data using Java

Comment: Can you provide us with the code that results in the given exception?

Comment: from the exception we can infer that you're using Java SDK 1.4.x, but can you share which version of the PHP SDK you used as well?